# aggregate function to project array size after removing empty value in array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

My primary goal is to print titles are having number of grades greater than four, i can achieve it with below query,

```
db.students.aggregate({$project : { title:1 ,_id : 0,  count: {$size : "$grades"}}},{$match: {"count": {$gt:4}}})
```

But if grades array have empty values how can i remove them, tried this but not giving correct output.

```
db.students.aggregate({$project : { title:1 ,_id : 0,  count: {$size : "$grades"}}},{$match: {"count": {$gt:4},grades : {$ne:''}}})
```

Comment: Can you post a sample collection object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/index.html) to remove empty `grades` before you run `$size`:

```
db.students.aggregate([
    {$project : { title:1 ,_id : 0,  count: { $size : { $filter: { input: "$grades", cond: { $ne: [ "$$this", '' ] } } }}}},
    {$match: {"count": {$gt:4}}}
])
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's explain this with step by step of different different queries:

**All possible values in the collection `grades`:**

```
> db.grades.find()
    { "_id" : ObjectId("5cb2ff50d33f6ed856afe577"), "title" : "abc", "grades" : [ 12, 23, 1 ] }
    { "_id" : ObjectId("5cb2ff55d33f6ed856afe578"), "title" : "abc", "grades" : [ 12, 23 ] }
    { "_id" : ObjectId("5cb2ff5cd33f6ed856afe579"), "title" : "abc", "grades" : [ 12, 23, 10, 100, 34 ] }
    { "_id" : ObjectId("5cb2ff63d33f6ed856afe57a"), "title" : "abc", "grades" : "" }
    { "_id" : ObjectId("5cb2ff66d33f6ed856afe57b"), "title" : "abc", "grades" : [ ] }
    { "_id" : ObjectId("5cb2ff6bd33f6ed856afe57c"), "title" : "abc", "grades" : [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ] }
```

**Just filtered empty grades records as:**

```
> db.grades.aggregate([{$match: {grades: {$ne:''}} }])

    { "_id" : ObjectId("5cb2ff50d33f6ed856afe577"), "title" : "abc", "grades" : [ 12, 23, 1 ] }
    { "_id" : ObjectId("5cb2ff55d33f6ed856afe578"), "title" : "abc", "grades" : [ 12, 23 ] }
    { "_id" : ObjectId("5cb2ff5cd33f6ed856afe579"), "title" : "abc", "grades" : [ 12, 23, 10, 100, 34 ] }
    { "_id" : ObjectId("5cb2ff66d33f6ed856afe57b"), "title" : "abc", "grades" : [ ] }
    { "_id" : ObjectId("5cb2ff6bd33f6ed856afe57c"), "title" : "abc", "grades" : [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ] }
```

**Now project the grades count values in a variable along with required other columns.**

```
> db.grades.aggregate([{$match: {grades: {$ne:''}} }, {$project: {_id:0, title:1, count: {$size: "$grades"}  } }])

    { "title" : "abc", "count" : 3 }
    { "title" : "abc", "count" : 2 }
    { "title" : "abc", "count" : 5 }
    { "title" : "abc", "count" : 0 }
    { "title" : "abc", "count" : 5 }
```

**Now match required condition of grades array count greater than 4 as below:**

```
> db.grades.aggregate([{$match: {grades: {$ne:''}} }, {$project: {_id:0, title:1, count: {$size: "$grades"}  } }, {$match: {count: {$gte: 4}}}  ])

    { "title" : "abc", "count" : 5 }
    { "title" : "abc", "count" : 5 }
    >
```